# chrome extension background page error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Why is my background.html page throwing this:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in line 1

Here is the actual html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancy-settings/source/lib/store.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

So chrome complains about the first opening "<" and I have no idea why.

Comment: Are you sure that the complaint is about this file and not one of the .js files?

Comment: Sounds like a JSON parsing error. That's at least what one would look like. Are you sure none of the JavaScripts loads/parses a file that is expected to be JSON?

Comment: Can you include your `manifest.json` file contents?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. Just replace in your `manifest.json` file

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
```

with:

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I lost 2 hours try to solve this. I knew that it had a stupid mistake but my eyes could not see it.

Answer (score 1):

remove js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancy-settings/source/lib/store.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
```

If the error persists, then you are not hooked up correctly js

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Manifest V3, just add type: "module" in the background

```
     {
        ...
        "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
        },
        ...
     }
```